# Saving changes to file through Google Chrome Developer Tools

Tags: html, google-chrome, debugging, developer-tools

How can I save changes which I make from `Google Chrome Developer Tools`. For example in following image I disabled a `css` property how can I save this change to respective file. If Google Chrome Developer Tools lacks this feature please mention some other tool.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Chrome DevTools Autosave will do the best for you: https://github.com/NV/chrome-devtools-autosave

Comment: In documentation of `Chrome DevTools Autosave` I found its obsolete because of `Workspaces` in Chrome, you may want to have a look https://plus.google.com/+GoogleChromeDevelopers/posts/644qQuBKZeL @user3107931